# Hunting bug in Meteor collection update

Tags: meteor

I’m trying out Meteor’s Leaderboard example and am running into a bug in trying to randomize the players’ scores.

The exception I’m hitting is `Exception while simulating the effect of invoking '/players/update' undefined`

The relevant code looks like this:

```
'click input.randomize_scores': function () {
  Players.find().forEach(function (player) {
    random_score = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)*5;
    Players.update(player, {$set: {score: random_score}})
  });
}
```

[Full leaderboard.js contents here](https://gist.github.com/2357254)

I get the feeling I’m doing something pretty silly here. I’d really appreciate a pointer.

Comment: That's a pretty unhelpful error message.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first argument to update() needs to be a document ID or a full Mongo selector.  You're passing the complete player document.  Try this:

```
Players.update(player._id, {$set: {score: random_score}});
```

which is shorthand for:

```
Players.update({_id: player._id}, {$set: {score: random_score}});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the Mongo intro :)